# Openlayers vector layer don't draw well on chrome (single tile)

Tags: openlayers-2, vector

I have singleTiled layer in OL (using chrome).
The layer don't draw completely unless I pan the map slowly to the south (here is example how the layer keep drawing itself each time I pan) :

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is how I create the layer :

```
var vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('vectors', {
    isBaseLayer: false,
    singleTile: true,
    layerName: 'vectors',
    displayInLayerSwitcher: true,
    styleMap: roadsStyleMap
});
```

Any idea why it happens in chrome only ? (in FF I don't have this problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From glancing at your screen shots, it seems like your whole vector layer is getting clipped at the same horizontal line.  I saw this once before and my fix was to change my CSS.

OpenLayers uses SVG for rendering vectors on Chrome (I'm 95% sure).  So whatever styles apply to the `svg` element might affect your vector layers.  When I had this problem, I added this to my stylesheet:

```
svg {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Then the problem went away.  This seems like a sloppy solution (since it just tells the `svg` element not to clip at its boundaries), and I never identified why the `svg` element was sized wrong.  But it fixed the problem and I never saw any ill effects.

You might also try using Chrome's developer tools to find your vector layer's `svg` element and see what size it thinks it is.

Comment: Interesting! I am currently struggling with point vectors that are just not shown on a mobile device (Android, using Phonegap). Do you think that could be a similar issue? PS: works fine on Android when calling the web app, but not once it has been converted with Phongap